# Showing array values from php function

Tags: php, arrays

My function `getStockStatus($stock_Id)` returns

```
array(3) { ["pqty"]=> string(2) "10" ["sqty"]=> int(20) ["cqty"]=> int(-10) }
```

(as var_dump).

If I use `getStockStatus(12)['pqty']` I get an error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';' in D:\xampp\htdocs\acs\ac_stockstatus.php on line 50`.

How to use this function?

Comment: firstly run this code getStockStatus($stock_Id) then you can get pqty

Comment: your approach is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

That kind of syntax was introduced in PHP 5.4. If you're using 5.3 or below, you need 2 steps:

```
$stockStatus = getStockStatus(12);
$pqty = $stockStatus['pqty'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are running on older version of PHP 5.3, this thing is handled PHP 5.4 or newer, see [Mannual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-102)

You need to store this in a variable to access.

```
$returnVal = getStockStatus(12);
echo $returnVal['pqty'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [array_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)php function if you want only values from this array you have.